# How to change legend scale - folium choropleth map

Tags: legend, choropleth, folium

I have some sort of error with the scale of the legend on my choropleth map in folium.

I have tried to use the bin size to change it but can't work out what I am doing wrong. no mater what numbers i input, the lgend changes in regards to colours on the map but they are still all grouped weirdly on the legend

[this is what the map looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7iJR.png)

here is the code

```
bins = list(dfForces1['Total'].quantile([0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9, 1]))
m1 = folium.Map(location=[50, 3], zoom_start=6.5, tiles='Mapbox Bright')
m1.choropleth(
    geo_data=forces_json, #this is reading the geographical data from the json file
    data=dfForces1, #this is reading my df
    columns=['Police force sent NRM referral for Crime Recording', 'Total'], #which columns do I want it to read
    key_on='feature.properties.objectid',
    fill_color='YlGn',
    fill_opacity=0.8,
    line_opacity=0.3,
    bins= bins,
    nan_fill_color = 'white',
    legend_name='Number of NRM Referrals Received',
    highlight=True
)
```

Comment: did you find any way around?

Comment: You need to adjust your bins value range to reflect the range of your data.